# Flatten future inside yield

Tags: scala

In the code below `x` is type `Future[Future[Int]]` and I need to flatten it to become `Future[Int]`. How is this possible?

```
   def times(a:Int, b:Int) = Future { a * b }

   val x = for {
     x1 <- Future { 1 }
     x2 <- Future { 2 }
   } yield {
      val future = times(x1,x2)
      future.map { result => result * 2 }
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the same for-comprehension. As `times` returns `Future` taking input `x1` and `x2`. You can use same for-comprehension to extract the value out of the future.

```
def times(a:Int, b:Int) = Future { a * b }

val x = for {
  x1 <- Future { 1 }
  x2 <- Future { 2 }
  result <- times(x1,x2)
} yield (result * 2)
```

Remember for-comprehension is a syntactic sugar for `flatMap`s and one final `map`

The whole thing can be written as

```
Future { 1 }.flatMap { x1 => Future { 2 }.flatMap { x2 => times(x1, x2).map { result => result * 2 }}}
```

Warning: As you are creating data independent futures inline (inside the for-comprehension or inside the flatMap). These futures will execute sequentially.

As first and second futures are data independent. They can be executed parallelly if you have created them outside the for-comprehension or flatMap.

**Flatten futures**

*Use `flatMap` to convert `Future[Future[Int]]` into `Future[Int]`*

```
def times(a:Int, b:Int) = Future { a * b }

val x = (for {
  x1 <- Future { 1 }
  x2 <- Future { 2 }
} yield {
  val future = times(x1,x2)
  future.map { result => result * 2 }
}).flatMap(identity) // <--- notice flatMap here around the for-comprehension
```

For clarity above code can be re-written as

```
def times(a:Int, b:Int) = Future { a * b }

val x = for {
  x1 <- Future { 1 }
  x2 <- Future { 2 }
} yield times(x1,x2).map(_ * 2)

val finalResult = x.flatMap(identity)
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def times(a:Int, b:Int) = Future { a * b }

    val x = for {
      x1 <- Future { 1 }
      x2 <- Future { 2 }
    } yield times(x1,x2).map(_ * 2)

    val finalResult = x.flatMap(x => x)


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> finalResult
res0: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(4))
```

Comment: where do you define identity?

Comment: @ps0604 Its available by default in Scala(Predef) without any special import.

Comment: @ps0604 You can use this instead `x.flatMap(x => x)`

Comment: @ps0604 indentity is nothing but `def identity[A] = (x: A) => x`

Comment: You can also use `.flatten` instead - same effect as `.flatMap(identity)` but more readable without the need to pass a function argument.